# Преобразование char в const char*

Tags: c++, char, const

```
const char * str;
int kolich = help.size();
double znachen(0.0);
for(size_t i(0); i <= help.size(); i++)
{
    str = help[i];
    znachen += atof(str) * pow(10.0, kolich);
    kolich--;
}
return znachen;
```

Эта функция принимает вектор типа char и возвращает число. В каждой ячейке вектора хранится одна цифра. Для преобразования из char в double использую функцию atof. Но она в качестве аргумента берет const char*. И тут появляется ошибка и вопрос. Как мой элемент типа char сделать const char*?

Comment: `str = &(help[i]);`

Comment: Обратите внимание на `std::string` вместо `std::vector` и функцию `std::stod`.

Comment: `i <= help.size()` - ох, что-то не так с условием :)

Comment: @Sublihim Что не так с условием?

Comment: @Alexeika74 когда i станет равным size() что будет лежать в help[i] ?

Comment: @Sublihim Согласен, тут мое упущение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас `std::vector<char>`, то надо взять адрес у элемента.

```
str = &(help[i]);
```

Этого недостаточно для функции atof, т.к. она на вход получает 0-детерминированную строку.

В вашем случае, если никак нельзя отказаться от `std::vector<char>` и очень хочется преобразовать именно `char` в число, можно применить не самый оптимальный трюк - преобразовать `char` в `std::string`

```
for(size_t i = 0, l = help.size(); i < l; ++i)
{
    std::string str(1, help[i]);
    znachen += atof(str.c_str()) * pow(10.0, kolich);
    kolich--;
}
```

Comment: Не забудьте, что строка должна быть нуль-терминированной.

Comment: Данный трюк мне известен. Интересует именно char

Answer (score 0):

У вас явная нестыковка. Если у вас векторов символов, и они **все вместе** составляют число типа `double`, то вам ответил @Sublihim, но при этом выглядит глупо проход по всем элементам вектора в цикле с использованием `pow` и **не** обработкой точки и т.п.

Если же вы хотите **для каждого** элемента вектора получить одноциферное число - из `'1'`, например, `1` - то просто пишите

```
int n = help[i] - '0';
```

Comment: Суть в том, что я из файла читаю в вектор типа char. После мне надо сделать преобразования с прочтенными числами, но для этого надо перегнать их в double. Из файла читаю посимвольно и получается, что в каждой ячейке вектора хранится одно число.

Comment: Число или символ? По-моему, вы сами немного запутались...

Comment: Я пишу с точки зрения математики. В каждой ячейки цифра. Во всем векторе число

Comment: @Alexeika74 так может и подходить с точки зрения математики? Преобразовать массив char в число и поразрядно производить необходимые манипуляции? Сдается мне, что процессор гораздо охотнее работает с числами, нежели с символами :)

Comment: @Sublihim Так и хочу так, только не получается из char в double перейти.

Comment: @Alexeika74, так может вообще именно из вычислительной части исключить char?

Comment: @Sublihim так из файла я именно символы в вектор char читаю. Как по-другому, не совсем понимаю

Comment: файл -> std::string (тот же массив char) -> целое число -> работа с каждым разрядом целого числа согласно вашего алгоритма

Comment: @Sublihim Такой вариант есть уже исполненный. Меня интересовала работа именно с char, так как была уже похожая ошибка в ранних работах

Comment: Читайте `isream >> double` и не мучайтесь...